# How can I run npm install succesfully

Tags: firebase, logging, vuejs2, npm-install, updates

I have a problem from upload my VueJs@2/firebase project.
My last work version is at 11/2021.
But all version of components need to be update.
So npm install don't success to install and update all.

I need your help to say me what should I do to work again on this project.
I joined [a complete log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sBrqMBiz7jNLKUUsAPvrdybTEHgGWahq/view?usp=sharing) of run `npm install` and my [package.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x2WSjM6mk51pTmsHXeL6iTXYGf13ynN8/view?usp=sharing).

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`npm outdated` will identify packages that should be updated.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lp-kHUhaTD5q7_9ChKDaAVhWbeRJTtQ-/view?usp=sharing And then ?

Comment: Even if I install just one component I got : https://docs.google.com/document/d/19FVKUshCGjVza46bM-EXklR1nwkrOrOIVNBn3foI_JI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: and then this https://nodejs.dev/learn/update-all-the-nodejs-dependencies-to-their-latest-version

Comment: thank for your help but finally I have for npm install after ``ncu -u`` : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GQIlA8zE_YLaKmsuKRNtAVHwK9xPBtyZdenoTvHdY28/edit?usp=sharing